# Ant Design theme switch animation [React]

Tags: reactjs, themes, antd

I use the Ant Design UI components library, and I've noticed there's an option for an impressive theme change animation. You can see it on the library's page at https://ant.design/ when you toggle the theme using the buttons at the bottom right. This animation involves a growing circle that starts from the toggle theme button and expands to cover the entire website.

However, in my own React applications, when I toggle the theme, only a fading animation is applied to all the components. How can I achieve a similar effect or the same result?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks like antd does not provide any option to apply this [animation](https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/pull/44655/files). You can create an issue in antd github.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the current moment this is only an experimental feature and it's not available for we to use.

You can read (and continue) the discussion [here](https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/discussions/45175)

Comment: That's weird! Thanks for the info :D